# VSCode: RuboCop cannot find .rubocop.yml

Tags: visual-studio-code, rubocop

How to fix VSCode RuboCop?

1. Where is RuboCop?
   `$ which rubocop`
2. Here it is.
   output: `/Users/georgenorris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rubocop`
3. Add it to VSCode configs:
   [image]

Then...
[image]

4. RuboCop is lost

**How to fix VSCode RuboCop?**

Comment: 1. Did it work before? 2. It can’t find the yml file with your configuration, are you expecting it to use a default config?

Comment: Does `/Users/georgenorris/Code/Calcite/.rubycop.yml` exist?

Answer (score 2):

Is the problem that [the extension](https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop) is no longer formatting your files?

If so I believe Rubocop 0.87.0 changed this behaviour breaking the plugin, see [#8156](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/8156).

The extension will need to be updated to fix this. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop/issues/123).